# Does CCA security imply perfect secrecy?

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, perfect-secrecy

Can any encryption scheme that is CCA (Chosen Ciphertext Attack) secure be considered to achieve perfect secrecy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perfect secrecy & [the traditional/standard definition of] CCA security are incompatible.

Shannon's theorem says that if you want perfect secrecy, then the key needs to be longer than the *total length of all plaintexts* encrypted under that key. But in the CCA game there is a single key, and no *a-priori* limit to the total number of encryptions (and hence total plaintext length) that an attacker can request under that key.